# Return the coordinates of my mouse click on the turtle screen

Tags: function, python-3.6, turtle-graphics

These are the function that I've been using

```
def getPos(x,y):
    print("(", x, "," ,y,")") 
    return

def main():
    turtle.onscreenclick(getPos)
```

When called they print the x and y coordinates which is great but then I can't do anything with them. I just need to store them somewhere so I can use them for later.  I am making a hang man game.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you want the functionality you describe to implement a hangman game -- my guess is you're not thinking about this in an event-driven way.  Regardless, here's a program that implements what you describe:

```
from turtle import Screen

def getPos(x, y):
    clicks.append((x, y))

def display():
    print(clicks)
    clicks.clear()

screen = Screen()

clicks = []

screen.onscreenclick(getPos)
screen.onkeypress(display, "P")

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

You can click all over the blank screen and when you type "P" (capital letter), it will print to the console a list off all the places you clicked and clear that list so you can accumulate more of them.